# Open and close accordion on click a link using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to open and close an accordion through a link. I am using jQuery.

You can see the fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/x1epjfv7/11/

The accordion works well if I just click the panel.

Steps to reproduce the issue -

```
1. Click the "Read more title 1" link - it will open the "Title 1" box
2. Click the "Title 1" box to close the panel - The toggle works well.
3. Now redo step 1 - Works fine
4. Redo step 2 - The panel doesn't close, which is the issue. It works when I click the panel second time.
```

```js
$("a.button").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(".accordion-wrapper div:nth-child(1) article").attr('style', 'max-height:inherit;');
  $(".accordion-wrapper input[id=1]").attr('checked', true);
});

//Closing the accordion

$(".accordion-wrapper label").on("click", function(e){
        const next = $(this).next()[0];
        if (next.style.maxHeight) {
            next.style.maxHeight = "";
        }
 });
```

```css
div input {
  display: none;
}
.accordion-wrapper{
  margin: 2rem 0;
  div{
    margin: 1rem 0;
  }
}
.accordion-wrapper article{
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
 overflow: hidden;
 max-height: 0px;
 position: relative;
 transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
 border: 1px solid #eee;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.accordion-wrapper label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #777;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background: #eeeeee;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.accordion-wrapper input:checked ~ article{
  max-height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="1" class="button">Read more title 1</a>

<div class="accordion-wrapper">
  <div>
    <input id="1" name="test" type="checkbox">
    <label for="1">Title 1</label>
    <article>
      <p>Content 1</p>
    </article>
  </div>
    <div>
    <input id="2" name="test" type="checkbox">
    <label for="2">Title 2</label>
    <article>
      <p>Content 2</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems the state of the hidden checkbox is still unchecked(false), and hence, the panel doesn't close on step 4.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to fix the issue by using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

**Here is a detailed explanation why it didnt worked with `.attr()`**

`.attr()`

- `.attr()` stands for attribute and it is used to get or set the value of an attribute of an HTML element.
- It operates on the attributes as they are defined in the HTML markup.
- It works with attributes like src, href, title, alt, class, etc.
- When used to set an attribute's value, it modifies the HTML markup directly.
- It works with both standard HTML attributes and custom attributes.
  Example: `$("img").attr("src", "newimage.jpg");`

`.prop():`

- `.prop()` stands for property and it is used to get or set the value of properties of HTML elements.
- It operates on the properties of the DOM element, not directly on the HTML markup.
- It works with properties like checked, disabled, selected, readOnly, etc.
- When used to set a property's value, it manipulates the underlying DOM property, not the HTML markup.
- It typically works with boolean properties or properties that represent the state of an element.
- Example: `$("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);`

```js
$("a.button").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".accordion-wrapper div input[id=1]~article").attr('style', 'max-height:inherit;');
  $(`.accordion-wrapper input[id=${$(this).data('id')}]`).prop('checked', true);
});

//Closing the accordion

$(".accordion-wrapper label").on("click", function(e){
        const next = $(this).next()[0];
        if (next.style.maxHeight) {
            next.style.maxHeight = "";
        }
 });
```

```css
div input {
  display: none;
}
.accordion-wrapper{
  margin: 2rem 0;
  div{
    margin: 1rem 0;
  }
}
.accordion-wrapper article{
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
 overflow: hidden;
 max-height: 0px;
 position: relative;
 transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
 border: 1px solid #eee;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.accordion-wrapper label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #777;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background: #eeeeee;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.accordion-wrapper input:checked ~ article{
  max-height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="1" data-id="1" class="button">Read more title 1</a>

<div class="accordion-wrapper">
  <div>
    <input id="1" name="test" type="checkbox">
    <label for="1">Title 1</label>
    <article>
      <p>Content 1</p>
    </article>
  </div>
    <div>
    <input id="2" name="test" type="checkbox">
    <label for="2">Title 2</label>
    <article>
      <p>Content 2</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```